# Setting image from url on List item click

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, imageview, baseadapter

I have a custom list view. On List items i have multiple URLs of images (added in Array list). Under list view I have a image view. On list item click i want to set URL image here. But every time i click on list item i am getting the URL of last item.Now i am using a Ion Library to set Image. Please Help !!
Code :

```
     ArrayList <String>url_list = new ArrayList<String>();

ImageView footerimage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView14); 

url_list.add("url1");
url_list.add("url2");
url_list.add("url3");

mainListViews.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String urlss = url_list.get(i);
                Log.d("urliss",urlss);

                Ion.with(footerimage)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.more_logo)
                        .error(R.drawable.more_logo)
                        .load(urlss);

                String texturl = next_prev_list.get(i);
                CustomAdapter1.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you are trying to set a different url to each list item. In your code I can't see where you are getting the **position** of the current list item.

In your activity (e.g. main) you should create your listener and then get the current position of the clicked item.

```
adapter.getItem(position); // adapter is your adapter name
```

After getting the current position you can assign the url to the item.

If this is not the answer you are seeking, please provide the code for all the classes you have so I can have a better understanding and help you more

Comment: you are  right brother!! i am taking the list potion instead of adapter potion!! I solved it before your answer , but thanks for the support :)